# Unrecognized grouping construct

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

I have a regex that is supposed to get the string between to known strings but it keeps throwing an exception:

> Unrecognized grouping construct

My code:

```
Match matchKey = Regex.Match(m.Value, @"(?s*)key(.*?)</dt>");
```

Key is the first known string and `</dt>` is the second.

What's wrong here that I don't get?

Comment: Can I have a string example of what you're trying to match?

Comment: What's `(?s*)` supposed to match?

Comment: you need to escape `(` by `\(` if you want to match parenthesis. Else the `?` does not make sense - its a special symbol to match `0` or `1` times of the "before" thing - and there is nothing before it... if you want to match ? - escape is as well

Answer (score 1):

This pattern doesn't compile. You need to escape `/` with `\`.
Secondly, add, you need to add a name to the group:

```
(?<first>s*)key(.*?)<\/dt>
```

And if in case you want to match  literally, you need to escape `<`,`/`,`>` also.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a good website to try Regex. It will describe your pattern in great detail and also point out any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your Regex and it indeed doesn't work. Notes:

- `(?s*)`: If you want to capture this group, you'll either have to drop 
  the `?` or add a group name, like `(?<g1>s*)`
- `(?<g1>s*)`: This matchs a string of 0 to N times the char `s`, is that what you really want?
- `</dt>`: the / should be escaped like this `<\/dt>`

Here's a regex that I tried on the string `ssssskeySomething</dt>`:

`(s*)key(.*?)<\/dt>`

If you want to capture an unkown string before `key` and before `</td>` then it should be like this (tested on `SomethingkeySomething</dt>`):

```
(.*)key(.*?)<\/dt>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your immediate question is `(?` is not a valid grouping construct. For a list of valid group constructs may I recommend you go to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and in the bottom right in 'Quick Reference' select 'group constructs'. This is also a really good website for building and testing your search.

After fixing this group construct though there is still the issue that you have not escaped `/` charcter so this will also return an error.

Let's break down step by step what is going on:

`(?s*)key(.*?)</dt>` is what you are searching for.

`(?` is not a valid grouping construct and is the reason you are getting the error. Depending on what it is you are trying to do you can change this to a capturing group by removing the `?` or a non-capturing group by changing it to `(?:` or if you are trying to do something different it may need a different change entirely. I can't really say much more on this without knowing what exactly you want.

`s*` matches 0 or more s characters

`)` closes the grouping construct

`key` matches key literally

`(.*?)` matches 0 or more of any character. This is within a capturing group. The `?` makes the quantifier lazy so it will match as few as possible.

`</dt>` will give an error because any use of `/` in regex has to be escaped (`\/`). Changing this to `<\/dt>` will match `</dt>` literally.

So after changing these two errors we get something like: `(?:s*)key(.*?)</dt>`

This now works. However, I do not know if it does what you want it to do as I have little indication of what it is you are really trying to do.